# printing style attribute dynamically with Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm trying to display a tournament tree:

Initially, I have a lot of  like:

```
<div class="match-wrapper"
           style="top:  {{ match['matchWrapperTop'] }}px; left:  {{ match['matchWrapperLeft']  }}px; width: {{matchWrapperWidth}}px;">
```

But I get :

```
WARNING: sanitizing unsafe style value top: -72px; left: 168px; height: 54px; (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss).
```

Now, I tried to change it like that:

```
<div class="match-wrapper"
           [ngStyle]="{top: match['matchWrapperTop'], left: match['matchWrapperLeft'], width: matchWrapperWidth}">
```

But now, I have:

```
Cannot find a differ supporting object
```

And this error is much less explicit...

What should I do???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing a full example it is a bit hard to tell. Based on the code you shared above and the [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#style-binding), it looks like you would want the following:

`[style.top.px]="match['matchWrapperTop']"`

Comment: it seems to be working, but I still have the message: Cannot find a differ supporting object

Comment: Please update your question with what your `match` object looks like.

Comment: dont bother, it seems it was a chrome error, after chrome restart, I no longer have the message. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1):

> **Simple** style binding

It's great for single value

```
<div class="match-wrapper" [style.top.px]="match['matchWrapperTop']" [style.left.px]="match['matchWrapperLeft']" [style.width.px]="match['matchWrapperWidth']">
  Lorem Ipsum
</div>
```

> Using **ngStyle** directive

Better option for multiple css property binding

```
<div class="match-wrapper" [ngStyle]="{'top.px' : match['matchWrapperTop'],'left.px' : match['matchWrapperLeft'],'width.px' : match['matchWrapperWidth']}">
  Lorem Ipsum
</div>
```

With TS content

```
export class AppComponent  {
  match = {};

  constructor() {
      this.match['matchWrapperTop'] = 10
      this.match['matchWrapperLeft'] = 10
      this.match['matchWrapperWidth'] = 100
  }
}
```